Linux - Formating multiple-pattern-select with grep
What i want to do:
i have a virtual-host conf-file (linux-apache server), with several virtual-Host directories in ONE file.
This virtual-host conf-File looks like:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/virtual-host.conf  
#<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName aaaaa.de  
DocumentRoot /aaaa/home/htdocs/…...
</VirtualHost>
  
#<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bbbb.de  
DocumentRoot /bbbb/home/htdocs/…...
</VirtualHost>
.... 

Now, for each virtual host, i want to select the servername and DocumentRoot writing the results in a text – file like this:
ServerName aaaa.de    DocumentRoot /aaaa/home/htdocs    
ServerName bbbb.de   DocumentRoot /bbbb/home/htodocs  
 etc. 

one line for the output of each virtual host.
Until now:
with grep -e ServerName -e DocumentRoot virtual-host.conf
i get the following output, 4 lines:
ServerName aaaa.de  
DocumentRoot /aaaa/home/htdocs/…...  
ServerName bbbb.de  
DocumentRoot /bbbb/home/htdocs/…...

How can i change this output to the Output "each virtualhost-output in one line" ?

You can use Perl to remove the newlines from every odd line:
... | perl -pe 'chomp if $. % 2'


-p process the input line by line and prints each line after processing;
chomp removes the final newline (if any);
$. contains the current line number. $. % 2 uses the modulo operator which returns 0 for even lines and 1 for odd lines. 0 is considered false, 1 is true.


@iksmax: Either update your question or ask a new one. Newlines are not shown in the comments so it's unclear what your output is exactly.
